# Перемотка видео в браузере горячими клавишами из другого приложения

Tags: windows, autohotkey

Допустим у меня на 1 экране браузер с YouTube видео , на втором - программа для рисования. Клавиши пауза/воспроизвести и следующее, предыдущее отлично работают, когда я рисую и мне нужно остановить либо переключить видео, но когда я хочу промотать 10 секунд назад или вперед, то естественно я этого сделать не могу пока я не перейду и не кликну по окну браузера и не нажму двойной клик по стрелкам вперед/назад. Можно ли как то настроить чтобы я мог, пока пользуюсь другим приложением с помощью клавиатуры, перематывать видео в браузере?

Comment: Можно через Autohotkey

Comment: https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=42744

Comment: Что здесь не так? 
`#IfWinActive, ahk_class com.alias.TpWin32SketchWindowSketchBookPro8

^+Left:: 
    ControlSend, , {Left}, ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
    Sleep 50
    ControlSend, , {Left}, ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
return

^+Right:: 
    ControlSend, , {Right}, ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
    Sleep 50
    ControlSend, , {Right}, ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
return

#IfWinActive ; `

Comment: я хочу чтобы если я в Sketchbook Pro (фокус на нем) , то при комбинации ctrl+left/right , в окне браузера происходила перемотка видео, имитируя двойной клик по стрелке влево/вправо соответственно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, не заморачивайтесь с AutoHotkey, да и лишний софт на компе не к добру, если больше его никак не используете.

Есть расширение для браузера:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/streamkeys/ekpipjofdicppbepocohdlgenahaneen

---

Но раз уж заговорили про AutoHotkey, то доведём дело до конца… По ссылке какие-то базовые скрипты и ищут они "Youtube" в названии окна, что немного бред. Включил себе музочку, а в названии непосредственно трек. Если название трека слишком длинное, то надписи youtube там не будет.
Поэтому поступим иначе:

```
#Persistent

^PgDn::
ControlMedia("^{Left}")
return

^PgUp::
ControlMedia("^{Right}")
return

^+Left::
ControlMedia("^{Ctrl Up}{Left}{Ctrl Down}")
return

^+Right::
ControlMedia("^{Ctrl Up}{Right}{Ctrl Down}")
return

^Left::
ControlMedia("{J}")
return

^Right::
ControlMedia("{L}")
return

^End::ExitApp  ;

ControlMedia(key) {
    WinGet, chromeList, List, ahk_exe chrome.exe
    WinGetActiveTitle, prevActiveTitle
    Loop, %chromeList%
    {
        chromeHWND := chromeList%A_Index%
        WinGet, chromeProcess, ProcessName, ahk_id %chromeHWND%
        if (chromeProcess = "chrome.exe")
        {
            WinActivate, ahk_id %chromeHWND%
            ControlSend,, %key%, ahk_id %chromeHWND%
        }
    }
    WinActivate, %prevActiveTitle%
}
```

Тут:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Page Up</kbd> переключит на следующий трек, если видео поделено на timestamp
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Page Down</kbd> на предыдущий соответственно
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> назад на 10 секунд
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> вперёд на 10 секунд
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> назад на 5 секунд
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> вперёд на 5 секунд
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>End</kbd> прекратить выполнение скрипта

Работать будет с Chrome, если нужен другой браузер, поменять. После выполнения вернётся в активное окно.

Версию под Autohotkey v2.0 можно получить через [конвертер](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=25100)

---

###### UPD

А нет, вру, даже в самом длинном названии всё равно в конце будет "— Youtube". Но, anyway, предложил элегантное решение по переключению обратно в окно.